# I need an ARM 9 Development Board

Tags: arm, vga

Does anyone know an ARM 9 development board that has Ethernet, USB and a VGA or TV out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose an Hawkboard ([hawkboard.org](http://hawkboard.org)). The Open-RD is an interesting device, but quite big. The Hawkboard provides an ARM9 and a TMS320 DSP (OMAP L138). It provides all the options you want and even SATA.

Answer (score 1):

I've been meaning to get my hands on this for quite some time now: http://www.open-rd.org/

Answer (score 1):

maybe something from embeddedarm.com.

EDIT, embest may have something as well.  I prefer their beagleboard clone to the beagleboard and know they also have arm7 and arm9 stuff.

Answer (score 1):

How about the Witech [TE2410](http://www.arm9board.net/sel/prddetail.aspx?id=335&pid=200)? $85 for an ARM920T with Ethernet, USB and a VGA or TV out / everything you need. Anyway I would like to recommend their OK6410 with 4.3" LCD more, $139 for ARM11 dev kit including 4.3-inch display, Linux, WinCE and Android.

Yea I bought the OK6410 and I like it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Atmel has the [AT91SAM9263 evaluation kit](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card_mcu.asp?tool_id=4057)
Not a VGA output, but comes with a VGA tft screen

Answer (score 0):

If price is important and a 200MHz ARM920T will do the job, there will be the Sim.One from http://simplemachines.it, target price 99 euros. However it's currently in developer testing stage, not in production yet. (Disclaimer: I work on this)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://www.developmentboard.net/index.php/productdetail/Development+board/ARM9/SAMSUNG/S3C2440/MINI2440v2/info/1) help?

```
Specification    MINI2440v2
CPU              ARM9 - Samsung S3C2440A
MHz              400-533
RAM              64MB
NOR flash        2MB
Nand Flash       128MB
Ethernet         10/100M  Ethernet, RJ-45 connector
Serial ports     3
RS232            1
USB Host         1
USB Device       1
SD card slot     1
Audio Interface  In, Out, Mic
LCD connector    1
Camera Interface 1
JTAG             10pin JTAG connector
Bus              40pin connector
GPIO             34pin connector
Dimension        100x100mm
Linux            Open Embeddeed with Ångström
```